# creating two floating divs side by side with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I'm try to create a side by side div that have 100% height, i manage to get the first div working but the second one is cause problem, been trying to do this for the last 3 hours.

```
#mainWrapper{
    width: 900px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#fff;
}

/*leftColumn */
.leftColumn {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:100%;
    background:#fafafa;
    border-left:solid 1px #dedede;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}

/* Content */
.mainContent {
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    margin-left:252px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

example of how it's supposed to look like
http://i49.tinypic.com/ycef7.jpg

how it looks like at the moment.(tried everything dunno how to fix it)
http://i49.tinypic.com/2ryk5eo.png

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving explicit height to both the inner divs floated left, you should use `overflow:hidden;` on parent div, e-g:

```
#mainWrapper{
    width: 900px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/zYWjJ/2/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.  Your solution doesn't entirely either .. #mainWrapper would also have to have 100% height but then if mainContent's body extended beyond the height of the page its background would stop when you scrolled down.

Comment: Your fiddle link seems to be broken.

Comment: the only problem now is it extended beyond the height of the page its background.